# Vuejs types for component refs

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have following scenario: I have an component here:

```
<div class="border shadow p-2">
    <chart :config="barConfig" ref="linechart" />
</div>
```

Now i can access it like this:

```
let linechart = ref(null)
```

The thing is, `linechart` is not just a normal HTML element. Usuall i would do something like:

```
let linechart = ref<HTMLElement>()
```

But its actually an component. I can access the methods from it with

```
linechart.value.update()
```

But typescript throws me an error that `update()` does not exist.
I have tried this:

```
import chart from "@/components/chart/chart.vue";
let linechart = ref<typeof chart>();
linechart.value.update();
```

But still no luck. Is there a way to get the exposed methods without an typescript error?

To be clear, the `.update()` method works. Its just typescript that cannot find the method. How do i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out. Its actually written in the docs.

https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-template-refs

This works perfect:

```
import chart from "@/components/chart/chart.vue";

let linechart = ref<InstanceType<typeof chart>>();
linechart.value?.update();
```